# link jquery animations

Tags: jquery

I want to link several jquery animations one after the other but I'm having some issues. Let's presume this example:

```
<h1 class="first">This is the first paragraph</h1>  
<h1 class="second">This is the second paragraph</h1>
```

I want to turn the first one red then back to black then pass on and animate the second one the problem is i don't know how to link the two animations.

I should add that I'm getting messed up in the syntax can someone give me a more explicit example $(this).animate() where do i state the second part of the animation (ie return to the original state) and where do i insert the callback function (i think thats the name for the function that activates once the first one is complete)/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".first").animate({"color":"red"}, 500,
        function()
        {
              $(".first").animate({"color":"black"}, 500,
              function()
              {
                    $(".second").animate({"color":"red"}, 500,                
                    function(){
                        $(".second").animate({"color":"black"}, 500);
                    });
              });
        }
    );
```

Idea is to provide the callback function that will be called when the animation is done. So in the first case when the `.first` changes to red, it calls the given anonymous function, which turns it back to black, and then calls its anonymous callback function to turn `.second` to red... get it? =)

You can read more about[.animate() here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

P.S.

**Here is an example that works:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

             $(".first").animate({"color":"red"}, 500,
                function()
                {
                      $(".first").animate({"color":"black"}, 500,
                      function()
                      {
                            $(".second").animate({"color":"red"}, 500,                
                            function(){
                                $(".second").animate({"color":"black"}, 500);
                            });
                      });
                }
            );
        });
    </script>

</head>


<body>
    <h1 class="first" style="color: black;">This is the first paragraph</h1>  
    <h1 class="second"  style="color: black;">This is the second paragraph</h1>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i'm trying to wrap my head around it, i'll get it :) . for some reason your example doesn't work on my document but if i change color to opacity and remove the quotations i can animate the opacity, whats the prob there ?

Comment: well yeah it was there in the first place ? i can't image where else it would go. in the head of the doc.

Comment: Ok now I gave you an example that works for me... if that doesn't work for you, the problem is in your browser... I don't know what else could be the problem, so I also added the starting style for the H1 tags that has the starting black color... You can copy/paste the code under the P.S. part of my answer and save it to "animate.htm" file and run it and it should work...